# Convert dtype from int64 to int32

Tags: python, numpy

Basically, I am using python x32 bit to load from file a list object containing several numpy arrays (previously saved inside a pickle using python x64).

I can load them properly and check the contents but I cannot use them.

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32')
```

How can I convert the arrays element type from within the list to int32 so I can use them with python x32.

The error comes when I try to execute the following part:

```
a=np.bincount(np.hstack(data['Y']))
```

Looking at what is inside `data['Y']`
[image]

Comment: You don't have to convert them to `int32`, 32 bit system still supports `int64`. BTW, why do you mean by you can use them?

Comment: perhaps cast to a string then an int as a work around? `new_val = int(str(old_val))` ??

Comment: I have edited the question with more information

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As others have said, 32-bit versions of numpy still support 64-bit dtypes. But if you really need to convert to int32, you can use the [astype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int64)
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> x.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> y = x.astype(np.int32)
>>> y
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I tried this and I get the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'. This will work for a simple array. But I am working with a list of arrays.

Comment: So call .astype on each